# How to test a method that calls different methods inside?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

I have a method to unit test called `addSong(song,userId)` in service class. I am calling three methods inside it from `Dao class`. I am using Easy mock to mock `dao class`. In the setup I first mock all the methods I am calling in `addSong(song,userId)`, and then calling the `service.addsong(song,userId)` method fot test.

But I am getting the following error:

```
Java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
MusicPlayerDao.addSong(song)
Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:42)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
    at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:97)
    at service.MusicPlayerDao$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$45bc3ca1.addSong(<generated>)
    at service.MusicPlayerServiceImpl.addSong(MusicPlayerServiceImpl.java:43)
    at AddSongTest.addSongs(AddSongTest.java:90)
```

Here is my code:

```
private void addSongSetup() throws SQLException{
    this.album = new Album();
    album.setAlbumName("album");
    this.genre = new Genre();
    genre.setGenreName("genre");
    this.song = new Song("song",this.album,3,"artist","composer",this.genre);
    EasyMock.expect(this.dao.addSong(song)).andReturn(1).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(this.dao.addGenre(genre, 1)).andReturn(1).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(this.dao.addAlbum(album, 1)).andReturn(1).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(this.dao.userIdSongsMapping(1,1)).andReturn(1).anyTimes();
}

@Test
public void addSongs(){

    this.album = new Album();
    album.setAlbumName("album");
    this.genre = new Genre();
    genre.setGenreName("genre");
    this.song = new Song("song",this.album,3,"artist","composer",this.genre);
    try {
        System.out.println(this.dao.addSong(song));
        boolean status = this.service.addSong(song, 1);
        assertEquals(true,status);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My addSong method in service class:

```
public boolean addSong(Song song, int userId) throws Exception {

    MusicPlayerDaoInterface musicPlayerDao = MusicPlayerDao.getInstance();
    boolean status = false;
    int songId = 0;

    TransactionManager transactionManager = TransactionManagerImpl
            .getInstance();
    try {
        if (song != null) {
            if (song.getTitle() != null) {
                transactionManager.begin();
                songId = musicPlayerDao.addSong(song);
                song.setSongId(songId);
                if (song.getGenre() != null
                        && song.getGenre().getGenreName() != null) {
                    musicPlayerDao.addGenre(song.getGenre(),
                            song.getSongId());
                }
                if (song.getAlbum() != null
                        && song.getAlbum().getAlbumName() != null) {
                    musicPlayerDao.addAlbum(song.getAlbum(),
                            song.getSongId());
                }
                if (userId != 0 && songId != 0) {
                    musicPlayerDao.userIdSongsMapping(userId,
                            song.getSongId());
                }
                transactionManager.commit();
                status = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException | RollbackException | HeuristicMixedException
            | HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        transactionManager.rollback();
        status = false;
        throw e;

    }

    return status;
}
```

I don't know were I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: could you please add the implementation of Song (Gener and Album)? Did you implement equals and hashcode in these Classes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a `EasyMock.replay` statement after you record the expected behaviour. Something like

```
EasyMock.replay(this.dao);
```

From the [EasyMock guide](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html):

> To get a Mock Object, we need to
>
> 1. create a Mock Object for the interface we would like to simulate
> 2. record the expected behavior
> 3. switch the Mock Object to replay state

Answer (score 0):

try removing the following lines from the `addSongs` test case:

```
this.album = new Album();
album.setAlbumName("album");
this.genre = new Genre();
genre.setGenreName("genre");
this.song = new Song("song",this.album,3,"artist","composer",this.genre);
```

I assume that `addSongSetup` is invoked before addSongs (e.g.; `@Before`). You are reassigning values to your variables album, genre and song in `addSong`, which, I suppose, EasyMock cannot match to your mock setup in `addSongSetup` as (depending on how EasyMock implemented this)

1. you forgot to implement hashcode or equals in Song, Album, Genre or,
2. EasyMock uses Object identity (i.e., reference comparison)

I guess it's 1.